# WRT54G - how use port forwarding and VNC

Tags: router, home-networking, vnc, port-forwarding

Since I have my home network behind a WRT54G, the router has an external "real" IP address, and the PCs behind it have 192.168.xxx.xxx addresses.

I would like to be able to control one of them remotely - preferably using UltraVNC, but I am open to suggestions.

Since I can't directly address that PC from the internet, I figured I could address a port on my router and have the traffic forwarded to the PC (and the same in the reverse direction).

Is that feasible? Can anyone tell me how to do it (or point me to an URL that does)?

Thanks

Comment: Migrating to superuser; follow the "migrated to" link...

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, you just need to forward port 5900 TCP (the port usually used by the VNC protocol) from the router to the internal PC you want to remotely control. Thus, when you connect over the net using a VNC client through this port, the router will automatically forward the control to that PC.

Now that you have forwarded the port, you will need to find a way to easily identify your WAN IP (that is, your Internet address) online. For that, you can use the [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.org) service if you are using dynamic IP. If you are using static ip, keying in your IP in the VNC client "connect to" field should do the trick.

Cheers, let us know in the comments if you need more help.

**EDIT : added two links that might help.**

[Port forwarding for VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/support/portforward.html)

[Lifehacker : How to access a home server behind a firewall](http://lifehacker.com/127276/geek-to-live--how-to-access-a-home-server-behind-a-routerfirewall)

Answer (score 1):

**[Port Forwarding UltraVNC on the Linksys WRT54G](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT54G/UltraVNC.htm)** (skip the ad)

If your "real IP address" is automatically assigned by your ISP (dynamically, thus subject to frequent changes) you'll need **[DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/)**

Here's a tutorial: **[Setting Up DynDNS](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Setting-Dyndns_t13622.html)**

Choose DynDNS as your **DDNS service** in the WRT54G's configuration interface:

[image]

However, the easiest solution would be **[Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx)** (free for personal use): install [Teamviewer Host](http://teamviewer.com/download/index.aspx) on the home computer, use [Teamviewer Portable](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/portable.aspx) from a USB stick and remotely contol your PC at home from anywhere. the installation is a two minute job and completely hassle-free!

Answer (score 0):

About port forwarding:

1. Enter the Basic setup of your Router using any browser. Just enter 192.168.1.1 (this is the default address), then the user name and password.
2. Enter applications and gaming

   [image]
3. Here you can control the port forwarding:

   [image]
4. Visit [LINKSYS WRT54G port forwarding](http://www.portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT54G/WRT54Gindex.htm). Look for the application you are going to use port forwarding for - in your case search for VNC.
5. Follow the steps on the website.

Comment: Please do not rollback edits unnecessarily.